# The requested resource is not available error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Hi all I am working on **Eclipse 6.0.36** and using tomcat server.I am having an error said "The requested resource is not available"  error 404.I had seen other post on same question and this is the common error that many solution that I could find on google. But still cannot solve my problem.. I am also still new working on eclipse.If there any information that you need just ask me, before vote down.. there are so long codes that I need to show..

some says this might be caused by servlet command.My servlet,from web_bkup.xml files looks like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SourceCodeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.source</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

surely there is lack of information that I give and you all can ask for it. But if there any solution that you all can shared.Hopefully can solve my error

Comment: what is the url that you are accessing??

Comment: You said Eclipse 6.0.36. Is it tomcat plug-in version?

Comment: https://pc415:8443/PM_Portal/e-system.jsp?cmp=68&prj=12&img=images|project|corporatepark.jpg&usr=nWxQUep/PcE=

Comment: now i am try to remove file,restart,add back file.. hope it works...

Comment: i'm not sure about plug-in :(

Comment: still can't solve.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only given little information, I try to answer under a few assumptions.

The `404` tells you that Tomcat could not find the resource `e-system.jsp`. I now assume that you have a project `PM_Portal` in Eclipse that you have successfully deployed to the Tomcat server, meaning there were no severe errors in the Tomcat log files which stopped the web application from starting. I also assume that `PM_Portal` is the root context of your application.

From that information, getting a `404` after successfull deployment means that there either is no JSP file `e-system.jsp` in the `/WebContent` folder of the Eclipse `PM_Portal` project or the `Deployment Assembly` configuration for you project lacks a mapping for the `/WebContent` folder. In order to check this, you can `right-click` on the project folder and choose `Properties`. Open the `Deployment Assembly` property and check that `/WebContent` is mapped to the root folder `/` of the target deployment.

Hope this is helpful.